# Elasticsearch 8.3.2 docker org.elasticsearch.gateway.CorruptStateException

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Installed ES 8.3.2 using docker on my local dev machine. Before this installation I had ES 6.3.2 running and I had deleted all my test indices in 6.3.2 before installing 8.3.2 so that I would avoid any v6 issues with 8 on my local dev. When I attempt `docker-compose up --build` I get this error, right before my es container exits.

```
es_usamm-db          | org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service
es_usamm-db          | Likely root cause: org.elasticsearch.gateway.CorruptStateException: Format version is not supported. Upgrading to [8.3.2] is only supported from version [7.17.0].
```

How do I completely wipe out any elasticsearch docker data so that I can just install 8.3.2? I thought deleting all indices in 6.3.2 would have allowed a clean install of 8.3.2, but there must still be some 6.3.2 data persisting somewhere?

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es_usamm-db
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.2
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./server/elastic/scripts:/server/elastic/scripts
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - default
  kibana:
    container_name: kibana_usamm-db
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.3.2
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this on your forum post - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-8-3-2-docker-org-elasticsearch-gateway-corruptstateexception/310765

but you need to use a new volume instead of reusing the old one - or delete all the files in the volume directory from your underlying OS

even if you delete all the indices from the old node/cluster, you still have things like cluster state that are stored, and these are only compatible if you step through the upgrade process

Answer (score 1):

Well in that case, I would recommend to delete all your docker images, container, Volumes etc.

## Single Node Cluster

To get start with single node cluster you can refer below blog:

https://ashish.one/blogs/elastic-docker-compose/

Here is the steps from blog:

This cluster will include

- Elasticsearch
- Kibana

For other stack like APM, beats etc please refer above link.

#### 1. Make directory

```bash
mkdir docker-elastic
cd docker-elastic
```

### 2. Create `.env` file

```bash
# Password for the 'elastic' user (at least 6 characters).
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=yourpass

# Password for the 'kibana_system' user (at least 6 characters)
KIBANA_PASSWORD=yourpass

# Version of Elastic products
STACK_VERSION=8.2.2

# Set the cluster name
CLUSTER_NAME=docker-cluster

# Set to 'basic' or 'trial' to automatically start the 30-day trial
LICENSE=basic
#LICENSE=trial

# Port to expose Elasticsearch HTTP API to the host
ES_PORT=9200
#ES_PORT=127.0.0.1:9200

# Port to expose Kibana to the host
KIBANA_PORT=5601
#KIBANA_PORT=80

# Port to expose APM Server to the host
APM_PORT=8200

# Increase or decrease based on the available host memory (in bytes)
MEM_LIMIT=1073741824

# Project namespace (defaults to the current folder name if not set)
#COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myproject
```

Save and close.

#### 3. Create `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: "2.2"

services:
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: es01\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es01\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

      
volumes:
  certs:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

Save and close.

#### 3. Start

```bash
docker-compose up -d
```

#### 4. Stop

```bash
docker-compose down
```

#### 5. Stop with deleting network, containers and volumes

```bash
docker-compose down -v
```

## Multi Node Cluster

Please refer below official doc to spin multi node cluster.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file